# converting Infix to prefix conversion

Tags: data-structures, infix-notation

Recently I have went through some sites, 
for converting the Infix to Prefix notation and finally got tucked up.

I have given the steps which I have done..

Ex:- (1+(2*3)) + (5*6) + (7/8)

**Method 1:- (Manual Conversion without any algorithm):-**

```
Step1: (1+(*23)) + (*56) + (/78)  

Step2: (+1*23) + (*56) + (/78) 

Step3: +(+1*23)(*56) + (/78) 

Step4: +[+(+1*23)(*56)](/78) 

Step5: +++1*23*56/78            **--- Final Ans -----**
```

**Method 2:-**

*As per the site http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/infix-to-prefix*

```
Step1: Reverse it:-
       ) 8 / 7 ( + ) 6 * 5 ( + ) ) 3 * 2 ( + 1 ( 

Step2: Replace the '(' by ')' and vice versa:
       ( 8 / 7 ) + ( 6 * 5 ) + ( ( 3 * 2 ) + 1 ) 

Step3: Convert the expression to postfix form:-
       8 7 / 6 5 * + 3 2 * 1 + + 

Step4: Reverse it
       + + 1 * 2 3 + * 5 6 / 7 8     --- Final Ans -----
```

So, here I got totally hanged.

Could any one please provide some light on following things:-

1. On where I went wrong in the above 2 methods
2. Which is the right answer

so I can able to understand the concept more better.

Comment: I think both answers are correct - remember a+b+c = a + (b+c) = (a + b) +c

Answer (score 2):

Your method is not correct, look at the comment, it says that `( a + b ) + c = a + ( b + c )` . What about `(a + b) * c? (a + b) * c != a + (b * c)`.
According to your manual algorithm, you put the last `+` is placed to the front. It is not correct. If you use `*` instead of last `+` , where did you put it ? Just think about that, then you can easily find the problem with your algorithm.
Another algorithm for solving this problem is just parenthesis it  before proceeding. Replace every left parenthesis with the operator inside it.
Example, `((1+(2*3)) + ((5*6) + (7/8)))` then it become `++1*23+*56+/78`. Your algorithm is correct if the precedence of the operator inside is same. If it is not it will fail.

> NOTE : Your answer can also be obtained by the arrangement of parenthesis. `(((1+(2*3)) + (5*6)) + (7/8))` then it becomes `+++1*23*56/78`. But if the last one is `*` instead of `+` then it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. You meant to say that, Method 1 is wrong and Method 2 is right.... But generally (a+b) will be returned to +ab right?. 
And also, I have seen your shortcut trick. It is more easy to do the thing. But I just want to know, what step will make the Method 1 to behave rightly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in step 4. You can place that `+` in two places. You chose one from that two options. But if any operator precedence is there, then only one option is available. That is in the case of `*` , you only get one option. So in general if you get a problem like this, check what happen if the operator precedence is there. According to that place your operator. In this case, `+` will come before `*` and after `3`.

Comment: Hi Aaroh. I got the point. But, Could u pls explain the line, 
>>"But if any operator precedence is there, then only one option is available." with some small examples, so I can able to grasp more. Thanks.

Comment: Let's take an example, `1+(2*3) +(5*6) * (7/8)`. According to your method the  steps are
Step 1 : `1+(*23)+(*56)*(/78)`
Step 2 : `+1*23+(*56)*(/78)`
Step 3 : `++1*23*56*(/78)`
Step 4 :  `++*1*23*56/78`             
It is not correct, when you find operators with two different precedences it will fail.

Comment: Thanks aaroh. Is there a way or rule to correct, this error happened in the step 4. [I mean, when this kind of operator precedence ambiguity comes, is there any kind of rule exists to follow.] So, I can able to solve this one with little more ease. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**(b * b - 4 * a * c ) / (2 * c)    EQUATION--1;**
Now I will solve this mathematically by substituting different variables, and doing 2 terms at time.
**=> x=bb* ; y=4a* ; z=2c***
these above are the substitution of first time, use in eq 1
**( x - y * c )/(z)**
again doing the substitutions with new variables.
**=> i=yc* ;**
**(x - i)/z**
**=> j=xi-;**
**j/z**
Now this here is the base case solve it then substitute back all the variables accordingly.
**jz/**
Now back substitution

xi-  2c*   /
bb* yc * - 2c* /

**bb* 4a* c * -2a*/**

Answer (score 0):

The Manual conversion is correct because when we reverse the infix expression to calculate the prefix, the associativity of the expression changes from left to right to right to left which is not considered in the algorithm and often it is ignored.

Example: 
 expression:5-3-2   :infix to prefix(manual conversion)
  (-5 3)-2
  -(- 5 3) 2
  - - 5 3 2

now by the algorithm(if associativity not changed)
reverse expression: 2 - 3 - 5

postfix: 2 3 - 5 -

again reverse to get prefix: - 5 - 3 2

now see if we ignored the associativity, it made a huge difference

now if we change the associativity from left to right    to   right to left:

then :

reverse expression: 2 - 3 - 5

postfix: 2 3 5 - -    (like a^b^b to postfix: abc^^ because it is also right associative)

reverse - - 5 3 2